# Crystal not show in crystal report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to show my crystal report into my website. I can print this report but I don't understand why when I want to show data in crystal report viewer why it's not showing. I research in the website, then use `CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()` but I can not use it, it says

> Error  1   'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' does not contain a definition for 'Refresh' and no extension method 'Refresh' accepting a first argument of type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\GenerateQR\GenerateQR\default.aspx.cs    115 38  GenerateQR

This is my code

```
if (dtQR.Rows.Count > 0) {
            string dirprint = @"D:\GenerateQR\GenerateQR\Report\Qreport.rpt";
            //CR = new ReportDocument();
            //CR.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA4;
            //CR.Load(dirprint);
            ////CR.PrintOptions.PrinterName = @"\\10.4.201.89\SCX-5635";
            //CR.SetDataSource(dtQR);
            //CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CR;

            //CR.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"D:\ASD.pdf");
            ////CR.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
            CR = new ReportDocument();
            CR.Load(dirprint);
            CR.SetDataSource(dtQR);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CR;
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh();

        }
```

This is my code in aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />        
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looks like it should be

```
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
```

not Refresh().

Comment: Thank u for reply, but it's still not thing in crystal report viewer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dtQR.Rows.Count > 0) {
        string dirprint = @"D:\GenerateQR\GenerateQR\Report\Qreport.rpt";

        CR = new ReportDocument();
        CR.Load(dirprint);
        CR.SetDataSource(dtQR);
        CR.Refresh();
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CR;
```

Maybe you can try this way?